# How to load a script in ollydbg

Tags: debugging, ollydbg

I decided to start learning Reverse Engineering and picked Ollydbg to start my path. Figured out how to install plugins, but I want to run a script for specific program to help me with the reverse. It seems like I need script loader. Tried installing Ollyscript, but that came up with error for missing .dlls

My question is: Can you please recommend any other script loader for Olly and if possible with installation guide for it.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: For me, the latest OllyScript plugin (v0.94 I guess) wasn't detected by Ollydbg v1.10. The v0.92 worked. Maybe you should try this or a previous version.

Comment: You can try https://github.com/0vercl0k/ollydbg2-python or https://tuts4you.com/download.php?view.3275 or https://tuts4you.com/download.php?view.3512 you can also try x64dbg with x64dbgpy.

Comment: Fur future readers: The last patch to olly was back in 2013. Consider using more modern debuggers (x64dbg, Immunity, (new) WinDbg, ..)

Comment: Can you be more specific ?

Comment: I download ODBGScript v1.82.6 from www.tuts4you.com and extercted it thereare some files i read documents and learned how i can write my plugin but there are some problems : 1- there are two files : logapicall.osc and sample.osc how can open them ? in the document has wrotten try by mspaint.exe so i download it but i cant open them and searched about it on google and then download merkaartor-0.16.1 and but it couldnt open the files 2- i read document compeltly but there was not any discribe about how can use of ODBGScript v1.82.6 . is there any body to help me ? pleas

Answer (score 2):

ODBGScript is a really nice scripting library. https://github.com/epsylon3/odbgscript/blob/master/doc/ODbgScript.txt this is the documentation, but a quick google search should give you the library itself.

Answer (score 2):

As @Naz stated, you can use ODBGScript.

You can download it from here:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/odbgscript/files/English%20Version/

In my case, I downloaded `ODbgScript.1.82.rar`.
Copy the files to the OllyDbg (1.10v) folder.
I copied to the OllyDbg folder because this is also the Plugin's folder I defined in `Appearance -> Directories -> Plugin path`.
 * Notice that there are two Dlls:
 1. ODbgScript.dll
 2. ODbgScript_Win2k.dll

If you copy both of them it will appear twice.
In this picture I added only one:

[image]